MariaDB killed by OOM
I'm running MariaDB 10.5 on a Debian 11 VServer with 16 CPU cores and 32 GB RAM. Since no other services are running on that server, I'd like to optimize the MariaDB configuration for the available resources and the underlying app which uses the SQL database. At the moment there are more than 177,000 InnoDB tables, from which maybe 4,000-6,000 tables are being used relatively frequently (statistics show about 1,300 executed SQL statements per second average).
With the default MariaDB configuration the RAM usage was about 75% after running for a few days. My goal is to use 28 GB RAM (about 88%) and leave the rest of memory for the OS and other small services (like SSH, f.e.). I've used the MariaDB documentation, mysqltuner, several blogs and of course stack overflow for answering my questions regarding how to adjust MariaDB configuration parameters for 32 GB RAM and 16 CPU cores on Debian 11, when the files are being stored on a SSD drive.
mysqltuner seems to output insane values like "use 70% of available RAM for buffer pool size" - and then after runnig it again with the updated configuration complaining about something like "memory usage is dangerously high". That doesn't help at all. After some weeks with OOM I've also tried ChatGPT - WARNING: The output is absolutely insane! Don't try to use ChatGPT asking something like "give me the optimal MariaDB configuration for ...".
I found a SQL statement (here and in some blogs) which was promised to help getting the maximum memory usage of MariaDB:
SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size
+ @@query_cache_size
+ @@innodb_buffer_pool_size
+ @@innodb_log_buffer_size
+ @@max_allowed_packet
+ @@max_connections * (
   @@read_buffer_size
 + @@read_rnd_buffer_size
 + @@sort_buffer_size
 + @@join_buffer_size
 + @@binlog_cache_size
 + @@net_buffer_length * 2
 + @@thread_stack
 + @@tmp_table_size )
) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;

The result was a bit more than 12 GB, which is less than 50% of RAM. Using this configuration
# my_print_defaults --mysqld
--socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
--user=mysql
--pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
--basedir=/usr
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql
--tmpdir=/tmp
--lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
--lc-messages=en_US
--skip-name-resolve
--bind-address=*
--slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
--long_query_time=3
--log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain
--log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
--expire_logs_days=5
--character-set-server=utf8mb4
--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
--performance_schema=ON
--innodb_log_file_size=3G
--thread_pool_size=32
--innodb_io_capacity=1000
--innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
--innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
--query_cache_size=0
--query_cache_type=0
--innodb_flush_method=fsync
--innodb_file_per_table
--skip-external-locking
--key_buffer_size=10M
--innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
--innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
--max_connections=250
--read_buffer_size=128K
--read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
--sort_buffer_size=2M
--join_buffer_size=256K
--binlog_cache_size=32K
--net_buffer_length=16K
--thread_stack=299008
--tmp_table_size=16M
--server-id=2
--binlog-format=mixed
--log-bin=mysql-bin
--binlog-do-db=portal
--expire-logs-days=5

MariaDB ran stable for a few days at about 85% RAM usage, until it crashed because of OOM. Just maybe 3 hours before I saw a memory usage of 88%, which should still be fine (4 GB RAM left for the OS and other services). I can't really say what caused the DBMS to consume even more memory until OOM, finally - that's what the var/log/messages say:
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.714947] mariadbd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.718778] CPU: 6 PID: 358794 Comm: mariadbd Not tainted 5.10.0-32-amd64 #1 Debian 5.10.223-1
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.721574] Hardware name: Hetzner vServer/Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS 20171111 11/11/2017
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.723586] Call Trace:
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.724406]  dump_stack+0x6b/0x83
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.725316]  dump_header+0x4a/0x1f4
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.726237]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.727327]  out_of_memory+0x1bd/0x4e0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.728294]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xc02/0xcc0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.729608]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2de/0x310
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.730790]  pagecache_get_page+0x175/0x390
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.731802]  filemap_fault+0x6a2/0x900
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.732742]  ? xas_load+0x5/0x80
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.733606]  ext4_filemap_fault+0x2d/0x50 [ext4]
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.734864]  __do_fault+0x37/0x170
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.735849]  handle_mm_fault+0x124d/0x1c00
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.736877]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1b8/0x400
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.737955]  exc_page_fault+0x78/0x160
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.738877]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.739887]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x1e/0x30
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.740916] RIP: 0033:0x561b78fd7967
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.741800] Code: ff 48 89 42 28 48 8d 05 57 36 66 00 48 8b 95 00 f2 ff ff 0f bf 39 0f bf 04 50 48 8d 15 62 38 6d 00 89 fe 2d 0c 03 00 00 48 98 <0f> bf 14 42 01 fa 81 fa 7d aa 01 00 0f 86 f7 01 00 00 48 8d 15 60
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.745614] RSP: 002b:00007fde0f7e13f0 EFLAGS: 00010212
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.746775] RAX: 0000000000000325 RBX: 00007fde0f7e16a8 RCX: 00007fde0f7e14e4
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.748426] RDX: 0000561b796ab1c0 RSI: 0000000000001489 RDI: 0000000000001489
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.750017] RBP: 00007fde0f7e2210 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.751692] R10: 0000561b7b1eec98 R11: 00007fddd0004b80 R12: 00007fde0f7e14e4
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.753246] R13: 00007fddd0000c58 R14: 00000000000007cb R15: 00007fde0f7e14d0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.754918] Mem-Info:
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.756279] active_anon:89 inactive_anon:7892232 isolated_anon:0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.756279]  active_file:754 inactive_file:209 isolated_file:0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.756279]  unevictable:1000 dirty:0 writeback:0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.756279]  slab_reclaimable:23599 slab_unreclaimable:22685
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.756279]  mapped:648 shmem:1169 pagetables:16032 bounce:0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.756279]  free:49119 free_pcp:899 free_cma:0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.764043] Node 0 active_anon:356kB inactive_anon:31568928kB active_file:3016kB inactive_file:1200kB unevictable:4000kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:2592kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:4676kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 14323712kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:5296kB all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.770188] Node 0 DMA free:11812kB min:32kB low:44kB high:56kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.775609] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1934 31285 31285 31285
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.776910] Node 0 DMA32 free:121568kB min:4176kB low:6156kB high:8136kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:1884964kB active_file:56kB inactive_file:72kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:2080624kB managed:2015088kB mlocked:0kB pagetables:392kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:520kB local_pcp:4kB free_cma:0kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.783256] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 29351 29351 29351
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.784495] Node 0 Normal free:63192kB min:63372kB low:93424kB high:123476kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:356kB inactive_anon:29683964kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:48kB unevictable:4000kB writepending:0kB present:30670848kB managed:30063160kB mlocked:0kB pagetables:63736kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:6036kB local_pcp:204kB free_cma:0kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.791202] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.792326] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 2*4096kB (M) = 11812kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.795141] Node 0 DMA32: 1575*4kB (UME) 629*8kB (UME) 379*16kB (UME) 515*32kB (UME) 122*64kB (UME) 73*128kB (UME) 58*256kB (UME) 45*512kB (UME) 24*1024kB (UME) 4*2048kB (ME) 0*4096kB = 121684kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.799146] Node 0 Normal: 625*4kB (UME) 783*8kB (UME) 996*16kB (UME) 513*32kB (UME) 220*64kB (UME) 58*128kB (UM) 1*256kB (M) 1*512kB (M) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 63388kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.802869] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.804840] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.806749] 2029 total pagecache pages
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.807837] 0 pages in swap cache
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.808845] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.810151] Free swap  = 0kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.811041] Total swap = 0kB
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.811985] 8191866 pages RAM
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.812932] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.814054] 168327 pages reserved
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.815033] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.815970] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.817238] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.819254] [    660]     0   660    24971      342    69632        0             0 dhclient
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.821280] [    923]     0   923    54942       65    69632        0             0 cron
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.823196] [    924]   103   924     2105      194    49152        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.825242] [    929]     0   929    24971      800    73728        0             0 dhclient
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.827121] [    944]     0   944    20015       67    61440        0             0 qemu-ga
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.829116] [    948]     0   948    55199      788    77824        0             0 rsyslogd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.831082] [    953]     0   953     3472      225    61440        0             0 systemd-logind
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.833117] [    954]   106   954    18683      182    61440        0             0 ntpd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.834943] [    960]     0   960      930       45    45056        0             0 atd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.836819] [    963]     0   963   189622     4118   159744        0             0 fail2ban-server
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.838822] [    964]     0   964     3338      243    69632        0         -1000 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.840664] [    965]     0   965    54717       27    53248        0             0 agetty
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.842453] [    966]     0   966    54625       30    57344        0             0 agetty
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.844419] [  23992]     0 23992    26427      250   229376        0          -250 systemd-journal
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.846382] [  24313]     0 24313     5300      193    61440        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.848355] [  38510]   108 38510     2102      184    61440        0          -500 nrpe
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.850105] [ 298925]   107 298925  9267254  7881928 64045056        0             0 mariadbd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.852062] [ 359062]     0 359062     3338      219    65536        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.853811] [ 359063]     0 359063     3338      220    61440        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.855550] [ 359064]   105 359064     3338      241    61440        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.857298] [ 359067]     0 359067     3338      219    69632        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.859032] [ 359068]   105 359068     3338      240    69632        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.860768] [ 359069]     0 359069     3338      219    69632        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.862473] [ 359070]     0 359070     3338      219    65536        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.864191] [ 359071]     0 359071     3257       87    65536        0             0 sshd
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql kernel: [2417806.865899] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mariadb.service,task=mariadbd,pid=298925,uid=107

The answers from the MariaDB online documentation regarding memory usage aren't really satisfying and leave even more open questions. Some blogs give a better overview, but with all the information I've collected I'm still not able to limit the MariaDB memory usage to 88% (28 GB) RAM with the above configuration, avoiding OOM after some runtime.
Right now I lowered the innodb_buffer_pool_size value to 5G in hope it may not cause OOM again - let's see. The above SQL statement does now show a max. memory usage of <10GB, now, but when I use top, I see this already (just 1h after I've restarted MariaDB with the latest configuration update):
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 360029 mysql     20   0   20,9g  16,6g  22808 S  30,0  54,4  49:48.89 mariadbd

Right now I don't have any confidence that the current configuration does limit the RAM usage of MariaDB to any maximum, just because I'm not able to get any reliable/usable information about which setting affects the memory usage in which way. Just all information seems to be misleading, or is there maybe a bug in MariaDB?
Could please anyone who is more a MariaDB expert than me (I'm not...) confirm that my updated configuration with innodb_buffer_pool_size set to 5G should not exceed 28 GB RAM usage? Or did I do a mistake which must lead to OOM sooner or later?
UPDATE: Since log_error has no value on Debian 11 per default, I'll enable error logging as soon as I can restart MariaDB. For now I can only give something that was logged using journald (MariaDB runs with systemd per default):
Sep 30 05:57:57 sql systemd[1]: mariadb.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Sep 30 05:57:59 sql systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Sep 30 05:57:59 sql systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Sep 30 05:57:59 sql systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 1d 22h 36min 40.994s CPU time.
Sep 30 07:03:46 sql systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.26 database server...
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.5.26-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-log source revision 7a5b8bf0f5470a13094101f0a4bdfa9e1b9ded02 server_uid YHiJyILNthIj3vAKd9L/4VyUFrA= as process 360029
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 5368709120, chunk size = 134217728
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Sep 30 07:03:47 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:03:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=325161292512,325161292512
Sep 30 07:04:02 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=325747905024
Sep 30 07:04:08 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting a batch to recover 74312 pages from redo log.
Sep 30 07:04:17 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 16179 pages from log
Sep 30 07:04:26 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction 262159121 was in the XA prepared state.
Sep 30 07:04:26 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction 262159122 was in the XA prepared state.
Sep 30 07:04:26 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 2 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 0 row operations to undo
Sep 30 07:04:26 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 262159124
Sep 30 07:04:26 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 8892 pages from redo log.
Sep 30 07:04:27 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last binlog file './mysql-bin.000013', position 124026480
Sep 30 07:04:27 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of recovered transactions
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.26 started; log sequence number 327123749709; transaction id 262159125
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting recovery for XA transactions...
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction 262159122 in prepared state after recovery
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction 262159121 in prepared state after recovery
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 2 transactions in prepared state after recovery
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Found 2 prepared transaction(s) in InnoDB
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:43 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql mariadbd[360029]: Version: '10.5.26-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-log'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 11
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.5.26 database server.
Sep 30 07:04:43 sql /etc/mysql/debian-start[360075]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Sep 30 07:04:45 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:04:45 10 [Note] Start binlog_dump to slave_server(3), pos(mysql-bin.000013, 124027092), using_gtid(0), gtid('')
Sep 30 07:05:01 sql mariadbd[360029]: 2024-09-30  7:05:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240930  7:05:01

Before the OOM nothing was logged today. After I restarted MariaDB the log shows only that a crash recovery did run successfully.
UPDATE 2: The slow query log is empty, and I've just investigated the binary log between 3am and 5:30am. All I saw was business as usual (the binary log dump of then timespan is only 80 MB). Maybe a hand full of connected clients (but not at the same time), doing regular stuff. At daytime there's way more traffic, many connected clients accessing several tables in parallel, but the memory usage stays stable. 3:30am it was at about 85% usage, later about 5am at ~88%, then 5:30am OOM (happened at >90% usage in the past). What I can see in the binary logs doesn't point out any reason why the memory usage increased that much. The app doesn't use transactions, so each writing SQL statement is wrapped with BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT by MariaDB. It also keeps connections persistent to avoid connect/disconnect for each context.
UPDATE 3: As requested I'd like to update this post with the SHOW VARIABLES and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output in CSV format (separated by ;). But since this post has lots of text already, and the output is huge, I had to use an external storage. By the way, I had to restart the server about 3 days ago, because I saw 95% memory usage, and during some timespan I can't just let it crash. Now the server ran at about 84% memory usage for the past days - right now it increased to ~86% - it seems getting interesting now. When restarting I also took the chance to enable general SQL statement logging to a file, to be able to see reading statements also (the binary logs only store writing statements).
The SHOW VARIABLES output can be found here.
The SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output can be found here.
UPDATE 4: Finally I was able to investigate the recorded data of the two latest OOM crashes (1st 2024-10-15 ~08:55, 2nd ~11:28 at the same day). Since I think the output of SHOW STATUS is only interesting when the values have been collected over a range of time, I did so, and collected GigaBytes of information - in particular for SHOW STATUS the output of every minute. The result can be found in an Open Office spreadsheet (ca. 8MB) that is available online. The first table "Data" contains the collected data plus the time, and plus a column proccount which contains the number of active SQL queries at that time (SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST). The second table "Charts" I've used to collect some charts for several columns, which might display helpful information (but I don't really know what I was looking for, so it might look wild). During creating the charts, I've got the feeling that the number of open files may be the cause for the steady increasing memory usage of the MariaDB process.

Search for maria db logging. Even if you find no problematic database operation, you'll get some insights, like slow queries and what is running when an OOM occurs. And join us holistic detectives.

the database has an error log. post the content of as well

Sorry, it seems error logging using the log_error setting is disabled per default. I'll configure it later, 'cause I'll need to restart MariaDB for that. If I get any error information from that log, I'll post an update.
Anyway - regarding my current configuration: Should it limit anything to <=88% RAM usage during normal operation, or does it look to you like it's clear that must be an unnormal operation going on which causes the OOM?

the error log is usually not disabled , but post the content after the crash

@nbk These are the configuration lines from /var/log/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:
# When running under systemd, error logging goes via stdout/stderr to journald
# and when running legacy init error logging goes to syslog due to
# /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf
# Enable this if you want to have error logging into a separate file
#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log


It's a comment only, and the log_error variable during runtime is empty, too. So the only output goes to journald since MariaDB runs with systemd, and that output I've just updated into my post. Or is there any other place that you mean, where I should have a look for more error information?

the error shows only tht it started ok and doesn't show the error before the crash,  so you need to wait as i said already

It seems you have both slow logging and bin logging enabled. You might want to look in those for clues. (You can read the binlog via the mariadb-binlog command but hurry before the binlog files expire.) The things that stand out about your MariaDB servers are the large number of tables and high number of qps, so perhaps there problem is related to those.

@dbdemon I've just updated the post with more details from the logs. The qps number is an average, but the app has usage peak times from about 8am to 5pm, where the real number if qps is much greater. During this timespan the memory usage stays stable at about 85% (while the CPU is boring most of the time). Outside of this timespan there's nothing special, just way less traffic, and only a SQL dump at 3am. The SQL dump was leading to OOM in the past, but with 8 GB buffers it didn't happen for some days. I just set it back to 8 GB again (2:50am) and now (3h later) the memory usage is at 70%.

Maybe a bit unlikely, but it is possible that the RAM was used up by another program such as fail2ban. I have personally watched fail2ban memory consumption balloon during a DDoS attack. When this happens, the OOM killer doesn't necessarily kill the "offending" process, so it could have chosen to kill the mariadbd process instead. Have you seen any evidence of a DDoS attack in your logs?

long_query_time=1

"The app doesn't use transactions, so each writing SQL statement is wrapped with BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT by MariaDB." -- A single 'writing SQL statement' is automatically a 'transaction'.  Don't bother wrapping.

In the OS:  swappiness=1

To help  further, please provide what this asks for: https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

@dbdemon fail2ban is running on that server, but it doesn't even show up in the list of top, 'cause it's CPU and memory usage is tiny. I had to restart the server 'cause I saw ~95% memory usage of the MariaDB process, and at that time I couldn't let it crash. Since then the process ran with ~84% memory usage - just now it increased to ~86%. Maybe it's getting interesting now, and OOM isn't too far away from now.

@RickJames I'd like to avoid using swap. In the past the MariaDB server ran on a server which was configured with swap - but as soon as swap got used, the server performance was so low, that the app which uses the DB got massive performance problems (it wasn't really useable anymore). In fact avoiding swap was one of the main reasons to run the MariaDB server in its isolated VServer environment: Having a fixed amount of available memory, no need to share CPU with other busy services, MariaDB specialized OS configuration

@RickJames I've updated the post with output for SHOW VARIABLES and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS.  The log_slow_query_time variable value is one second now. Btw. I use InnoDB on that server only.

@nd_ - "swappiness=1" will delay (but not prevent) swapping. "=0" will prevent swapping but may crash the whole system.  (The default is probably "=60".)

@JoopEggen Finally I've got a complete crash record yesterday - the 1st day of my vacation, yey - and just 2.5h later another OOM. So now I've recorded many Gigabytes of data from the past days to the 1st OOM yesterday, and - I'm glad - the data of the 2.5h to the 2nd OOM. Anyway, at present I'm not able to investigate even the small dataset, but I'll update my post asap. I've also recorded the output of SHOW STATUS and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST of every minute in a separate database, which I want to use for making some charts which may show which runtime information behaves abnormal.

@nbk It seems because the OOM killer just kills the process, MariaDB has no chance to write anything into the error log. I always only see crash recovery information after a restart of MariaDB after OOM. The slow query log is empty also. That's why I decided to enable logging of all SQL statements and in addition store runtime status and process information of every minute in a separate database. That data I'd like to investigate asap and update my post maybe with a few charts.

@RickJames I saw your reply and will come back to it asap - but now I have to get to a flight soon...

@JoopEggen I've just updated my post with all collected information that I can offer. During investigating the data I've got the feeling that the number of open files could be the cause for the steady increasing memory usage.

Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
 

Observations:

Version: 10.5.26-MariaDB-0+deb11u2-log
28 GB of RAM
Uptime = 3d 04:14:26
1.2e+3 QPS


The More Important Issues:
Recommended changes to settings:
table_open_cache = 3000
table_open_cache_instances = 16
general_log = OFF      -- this ON fills up disk fast; use it sparingly
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0   -- if the disk is SSD
thread_pool_max_threads = 32768

Why is SHOW CREATE TABLE being performed so frequently?  Ditto for SHOW COLUMNS.
I can't explain why you are running out of RAM when innodb_buffer_pool_size is so low.
Use the SlowLog .  This may indirectly discover queries that are consuming RAM/disk during their operation.  (Cf, Created_tmp_disk_tables)

Details and other observations:
( Opened_tables ) = 47262193 / 274466 = 172 /sec -- Frequency of opening Tables
-- increase table_open_cache (now 2000)
( Opened_table_definitions ) = 47883427 / 274466 = 174 /sec -- Frequency of opening .frm files
-- Increase table_definition_cache (now 400) and/or table_open_cache (now 2000).
( Table_open_cache_overflows ) = 47248573 / 274466 = 172 /sec
-- May need to increase table_open_cache (now 2000)
( Table_open_cache_misses ) = 48212411 / 274466 = 175 /sec
-- May need to increase table_open_cache (now 2000)
( Opened_tables / Uptime / table_open_cache_instances ) = 47,262,193 / 274466 / 8 = 21.5 -- A metric for table_open_cache_instances
-- Increase table_open_cache_instances (now 8) to cut back on contention for the table_open_cache (now 2000).
( Table_open_cache_misses / (Table_open_cache_hits + Table_open_cache_misses) ) = 48,212,411 / (410329064 + 48212411) = 10.5% -- Effectiveness of table_open_cache.
-- Increase table_open_cache (now 2000) and check table_open_cache_instances (now 8).
( general_log ) = general_log = ON -- Log (FILE or TABLE) of all queries run.
-- Turn off the general_log (now ON) when not in use. That log can fill up disk very rapidly.
( Com_show_create_table ) = 538481 / 274466 = 2 /sec -- How often SHOW CREATE TABLE is executed. Possibly comes from a 3rd party package that is sloppy.
-- Check table_open_cache (now 2000) and open_files_limit (now 32313). Or avoid the 3rd party package.
( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 8,192 / 28672M = 28.6% -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool
-- Set to about 70% of available RAM. (To low is less efficient; too high risks swapping.)
( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,536 * 1 = 1,536 -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 1). Also check for swapping.
( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,536 -- innodb_lru_scan_depth is a very poorly named variable. A better name would be innodb_free_page_target_per_buffer_pool. It is a number of pages InnoDB tries to keep free in each buffer pool instance to speed up read and page creation operations.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth
( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 190,515 / 516160 = 36.9% -- Pct of buffer_pool that is "old".
( Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead ) = 742,297 / 3384916 = 21.9% -- Utility of read_ahead.
-- Turn off innodb_random_read_ahead (now OFF).
( innodb_log_files_in_group ) = 1 -- Number of InnoDB log files
-- 2 is probably the only reasonable value.
A large number may cause performance problems.
( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method = fsync -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT
( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine = 
( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = innodb_flush_neighbors = 1 -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.
( innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ) = 0 -- 1 = secure; 2 = faster
-- (You decide) Use 1, along with sync_binlog (now 0)=1 for the greatest level of fault tolerance. 0 is best for speed. 2 is a compromise between 0 and 1.
( sync_binlog ) = 0 -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster. 0 is OK for Galera.
( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.
( character_set_client ) = character_set_client = utf8 --
-- If you will be using text from places other than Western Europe, consider switching to utf8mb4. (Beyond the scope of this discussion.)
( character_set_connection ) = character_set_connection = utf8 --
( character_set_results ) = character_set_results = utf8 --
( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue
( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 1380509 / 274466 = 5 /sec -- Frequency of creating disk "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216).
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.
( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 1,380,509 / 3121337 = 44.2% -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.
( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)
( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)
( back_log ) = 100 -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections)
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 250)) may help when doing lots of connections.
( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 33 / 250 = 13.2% -- Peak % of connections
-- Since several memory factors can expand based on max_connections (now 250), it is good not to have that setting too high.
( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 250 / 33 = 757.6%
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.
( thread_pool_max_threads ) = 65,536 -- One of many settings for MariaDB's thread pooling
-- Lower the value.
Abnormally small:
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 0.0723
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 0.00036

Abnormally large:
Binlog_snapshot_position = 1.05e+9
Com_create_temporary_table = 0.042 /sec
Com_drop_temporary_table = 0.042 /sec
Com_show_fields = 2 /sec
Com_unlock_tables = 21 /HR
Handler_read_first = 247 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed = 560
Open_streams = 4
Performance_schema_digest_lost = 5.52e+7
Select_range = 82 /sec
Slave_connections = 2
Slaves_connected = 0.013 /HR

Abnormal strings:
Compression = ON
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
disconnect_on_expired_password = OFF
gtid_slave_pos = 0-1-1240419
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
log_slow_verbosity = query_plan,explain
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
optimizer_trace = enabled=off


I've enabled general SQL statement logging only for being able to see what happened before an OOM crash. Usually I would have disabled that option. The number of tables is growing in every day. A script does this automatic and uses table meta data to validate a correct setup. When setting the InnoDB buffer pool size to 70% of available memory, I can't even run mysqldump without an OOM crash. However, 70% seems to be the suggested correct value - I may come back to it later, when the cause for the OOM was found. Thanks a lot for your help!

"number of tables is growing each day" -- Ouch.  Please elaborate.  It sounds like a bad schema design.

A set of base tables is being added for each new tenant. A tenant may customize tables at any time (extend them with additional fields and indexes). An ORM is responsible for applying base table definition updates for all tenants and merging them with customized table definitions, and it's also responsible for applying any customization at the DBMS. That's the whole thing - I don't know any other way to realize such an application. That's maybe challenging for the app and the DBMS, but I wouldn't call it a bad schema design, or is it?

A slight improvement is to have a separate database for each tenant.  I suspect you "never" need to look at the "same" table for two different tables in the same query.
